# Google Spreadsheet fill rows base from data from different tab and sum the other field

Tags: google-sheets

I have a meal planner spreadsheet that gets the value from another tab like in the screenshot:

[image]

I have this formula to get the values:

```
=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TOROW(D6:D18)='Meal Ingredients'!A:A,'Meal Ingredients'!B:B, NA())),3, TRUE)
```

These are the entries from Meal Ingredient:

[image]

I cannot come up with a solution to sum up the quantity and cost, it should look like this:

[image]

How can I do this? And can I incorporate my initial formula?

Comment: Please include text-based examples, such as by sharing an editable sample sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try with:*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(,tocol(D6:D18,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,filter({'Meal Ingredients'!B:D,'Meal Ingredients'!C:C*'Meal Ingredients'!E:E},'Meal Ingredients'!A:A=c)))),
       query(Σ,"Select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3,Sum(Col4) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col3 label sum(Col2)'',sum(Col4)''",0))
```

[image]